# Catching fallen-off bytes in bit shifting in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

If you want to know whether a particular bit is set in a byte, a simple AND mask can do the trick. I want to know if there is a faster way to achieve the same. As an example, bit shifting << or >> returns the shifted number rather than the bit that just 'fell off'.

If there is no alternative in managed code, would writing unsafe assembly make it faster? If so, please explain how.

Context: This is for a complex algorithm that needs to be highly optimized for production code. I felt it necessary to clarify this to avoid the dreaded 'do your own homework' comments and/or vote downs.

Comment: You mean faster than `(x & MASK) != 0` ? What are you comparing to? What would you do in some other language (C or ASM maybe) to do this faster? Bit ops are pretty fast... and a `<<` or `>>` is not necessarily faster than a `&`... And no, `unsafe` won't really help you here, *unless* maybe the bit you are after is on a byte boundary, and testing that will take more time than just doing the mask operation.

Comment: an AND is very quick, it boils down to a single assembly instruction,  are you sure this is what's making things slow?

Comment: IIRC, some processors use [barrel shifters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter) and set the arithmetic status bits based on the result.  That said, AND sure seems like the simpler way to go and less likely to have an unexpected dependence on a processor feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted: bitwise operations are highly efficient. On any modern processor, virtually any such operation almost certainly executes in a single clock cycle.

If you want to see the actual code genn'ed for your expression, fire it up in the Visual Studio debugger. Set a breakpoint, when you hit it, click on menu: Debug..Windows..Disassembly.

Maybe, if your expression was sufficiently convoluted, you could beat the compiler and optimizer on this sort of thing, but I doubt it. More importantly, any performance issues you encounter are unlikely to be related to bit-twiddling. Don't optimize until you have a problem. As James Michael Hare says:

> Remember the two laws of optimization.  I'm not sure where I first
>   heard these, but they are so true:
>
> - For beginners: Do **not** optimize.
> - For experts: Do not optimize **yet**.
>
> This is so true.  If you're a beginner, **resist** the urge to optimize at all
>   costs.  And if you are an expert, **delay** that decision. As long as you
>   have chosen the right data structures and algorithms for your task,
>   your performance will probably be more than sufficient.  Chances are
>   it will be network, database, or disk hits that will be your
>   slow-down, not your code. As they say, 98% of your code's bottleneck
>   is in 2% of your code so premature-optimization may add maintenance
>   and safety debt that won't have any measurable impact.
>
> Instead, code for maintainability and safety, and then, and only then, when you find
>   a true bottleneck, then you should go back and optimize further.

More here:

- [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)
- [The Perils of Premature Optimization](http://scientopia.org/blogs/goodmath/2011/05/03/the-perils-of-premature-optimization/)

See [Bit-Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) for how to accomplish just about anything related to bit manipulation. Oriented towards the C language, but the same techniques work with little modification in C# (anything involving pointers might need some rethinking, for instance).

Comment: +1 for Disassembly. Regarding your comments about optimization, I agree and follow those guidelines religiously. The algorithm in question however, deals with arithmetic operations on numbers the size of 2 to the power 10,000,000 and needs to improve in execution time by 80%. Optimizing such a scenario has led me to research on a diverse set of strategies. Masking happens to be an operation that is very frequently performed in this algo.

Comment: The .NET JIT compiler is rather easy to beat really.. I would say anyone with a somewhat decent knowledge of assembly could do it. Also, don't forget *not fire it up in the debugger*, that will kill all optimizations and make the code look like it has been written by a dog. Attach the debugger later.

Answer (score 6):

To perform a bit-test via shift operations, you would have to shift it (unsigned) twice, to knock off the extra bits from either side (you don't need to put it back in any particular position - just test for zero). This is complicated and not optimal.

Strangely enough, an `&` is the standard way of performing a bit-test, and has been heavily optimized; this is a single CPU instruction, and is very very fast.

Just use the `&` test, for example `if((x & MASK) != 0)`.

No, `unsafe` code won't really help you here. `unsafe` is primarily interested in pointers. Pointers are fun and interesting, but you can do **exactly** the same bit-tests without them. One potential use of pointers here is if there was some way of using a pointer coercion to test *more* data at a time than was originally the case, for example if you have a `byte[]`, but you want to test it 8 bytes at a time, by forcing the `byte[]` to a `byte*`, and then the `byte*` to a `long*` or `ulong*`. This might be a useful optimisation in, say, web-socket masking (which operates on a byte-stream using a wider xor mask). None of this, however, is required for a simple bit test.